# What is the best way to parse filenames?

Tags: shell, parsing, pipe, sh, filenames

I was originally writing a command to periodically remove auto-generated Emacs files at a certain interval, starting at my current directory (before becoming aware you can disable this within Emacs):

```
#!/bin/sh

clean ()
{
    find . -name "*~" -type f | while read f; do rm "$f"; done
}

while true; do clean; sleep 1800; done &
```

I found that the above script doesn't always work. Here is why:

```
sh-3.2$ ls
FilenameWithNewLine?End One-Word-Filename   Two-Word Filename
sh-3.2$ find . -name "*" -type f
./Two-Word Filename
./One-Word-Filename
./FilenameWithNewLine
End
```

which leads to my question on the best way to parse filenames, specifically with regard to pipe milling.

To be clear, I am asking for a general method to parse filenames.

Here is another example:

```
sh-3.2$ ls > myfilenames.txt
sh-3.2$ cat myfilenames.txt | grep 'mypattern'
```

The above would not work due to to the same issue I mentioned.

I am searching for a general answer, and using examples to illustrate my point.

Comment: Many versions of `find` support a `-print0` option which will use a nul instead of a newline between outputs, and if you are using a shell with a `read` that supports it (eg, bash), you can do something like: `find ... -print0 | while read -d '' name; do rm "$name"; done`.  Note that `rm` is a bad example since `find` often has a `-delete` option, and if it doesn't you ought to be using `-exec` instead of piping to a shell, but the nul separator is handy.

Comment: See also https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020

Answer (score 1):

With a POSIX `find`, you can call `rm` directly:

```
clean ()
{
    find . -name "*~" -type f -exec rm {} +
}
```

This also works for more complicated shell processing:

```
find . -name "*~" -type f -exec sh -c '
    for f; do
        rm "$f"
    done
' -- {} +
```

Remember that there may be multiple invocations of `-exec` if there is a large number of input filenames:

```
find / -exec sh -c 'echo $#' -- {} + 2>&-
```

---

To handle filenames with embedded newlines, you need a format that is unambiguous. Nulls are not allowed in filenames, so using null-delimited I/O allows arbitrary filenames to be handled safely.

If you are less worried about POSIX-compatibilty, some implementations of utilities support null-delimited input and/or output. For example:

```
find -print0

xargs -0 

sort -z

grep -z

awk -v RS='\0'
```

Comment: cf. `sha512sum`, et al, which uses a leading backslash and escapes filenames that contain newlines or backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do:

```
clean ()
{
    find . -name "*~" -type f -delete
}
```